# Requirejs - modules listed in define sometimes (not always) undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

UPD: Problem was solved by changing RequireJS 2.1.15 to 2.0.

After few days finding problem in my code (using google) I decided to write here.
I have client side JS which use requirejs as base of architecture. But sometimes this system is not works correct, I see messages that modules which was listed in 'define' sometimes returns undefined value, it is cause of crash my application. But it happens not always, on the average every 5 page reloading and in different parts of the system. Below I attached real project structure and code of files where error can be thrown.

Structure:
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1973760/5637730/02370346-9629-11e4-88ef-00dfea7a5e1c.png

app.js

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'Lib/jquery-1.11.0.min',
        socketio: 'http://localhost:81/socket.io/socket.io',
        jquerytmpl: 'Lib/jquery.tmpl.min',
        jqueryui: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min',
        jquerymultiselect: 'Lib/jquery-ui/jquery.multiselect.min',
        css: 'Lib/requirecss',
        cookie: 'Lib/jquery.cookie',
        bootstrap: "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min",
        flatui: "Lib/flat-ui-pro.min"
    },
    waitSeconds: 200,
    shim: {
        socketio: {
            exports: 'io'
        },
        flatui: {
            exports: '$',
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        cookie: {
            exports: '$',
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});
require(['jquery', 'Router'], function($, Router){
    Router.startRouting();
});
```

Router.js

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    var routes = [{uri: /^\/$/, controller: 'MainPageController'},
        {uri: /^\/[a-z0-9_]+\/?$/, controller: 'PublicPageController'},
        {uri: /^\/public\/add\/?$/, controller: 'PublicAddPageCOntroller'}];

    function startRouting() {
        var currentURI = window.location.pathname;

        $.each(routes, function(k, v) {
            if (v.uri.test(currentURI)) {
                loadController(v.controller);
            }
        });
    }

    function loadController(controllerName) {
        require(['Controllers/' + controllerName], function(controller) {
            controller.init();
        });
    }

    return {
        startRouting: startRouting
    };
});
```

Controllers/PublicPageController.js

```
define(['jquery', 'socketio', 'Modules/ChatModule', 'Modules/NotificationModule', 'Modules/StatusModule', 'Modules/PageBuilderModule', 'Entity/Mediator'], function ($, io, ChatModule, NotificationModule, StatusModule, PageBuilderModule, mediator) {
    function init() {
        /**
         * Connect to socket.io server
         */
        var socket = io('http://localhost:81/?token=' + token);
        /**
         * init modules
         */
        var notificationModule = new NotificationModule(socket, mediator);
        var pageBuilderModule = new PageBuilderModule(socket, mediator);
        var chatModule = new ChatModule(socket, mediator);
        var statusModule = new StatusModule(socket, mediator);

    }
    return {init: init};
});
```

Modules/NotificationModule.js

```
define(['jquery', 'Entity/SystemNotification', 'Entity/ChatRequestNotification', 'Entity/Notifications', 'Entity/ChatRequestNotificationAcceptedByPair', 'Entity/UriModifier'], function ($, SystemNotification, ChatRequestNotification, Notifications, ChatRequestNotificationAcceptedByPair, UriModifier) {

    function NotificationModule(socket, mediator) {
        var notifications = new Notifications(socket);
        var that = this;
        this.addNotification = function (data) {
            switch (data.type) {
                case 1:
                    var notification = new SystemNotification(data.id, data.fields.message, data.fields.from, socket);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    var notification = new ChatRequestNotification(data.id, data.fields.from, UriModifier.getCurrentSlug(), socket,
                            function (err, data) {
                                mediator.publish('chatRequestAccepted', err, data, notification);
                            },
                            function (err, data) {
                                mediator.publish('chatRequestDeclined', err, data, notification);
                            });
                    break;
                case 3:
                    var notification = new ChatRequestNotificationAcceptedByPair(data.id, data.fields.from, socket,
                            function (err, data) {
                                mediator.publish('chatRequestStarted', err, data, notification);
                            }, function (err, data) {
                                //chatRequestCanceled
                                mediator.publish('chatRequestCanceled', err, data, notification);
                            });
                    break;
            }
            if(notification){
                notifications.push(notification);
            }

        };

        socket.on('notificationsLoaded', function (data) {
            $.each(data.notifications, function (k, v) {
                that.addNotification(v);
            });
        });
    }
    return NotificationModule;

});
```

Entity/SystemNotification

```
define(['jquery','Entity/Notification','Views/SystemNotificationView'], function ($, Notification, SystemNotificationView) {
    function SystemNotification(id, message, from, socket) {
        var parent = Notification.call(this, id, socket);
        parent.setView(new SystemNotificationView(id, 'Системное уведомление', message, from));
    };

    return SystemNotification;
});
```

Entity/Notification

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    return function (id, socket) {
        var that = this;
        this.append = function () {
            this.view.append();
        };
        this.close = function () {
            this.view.close();
            socket.emit('closeNotification', {id: id});
        };
        this.getId = function () {
            return id;
        };

        return {
            setView: function (v) {
                that.view = v;
                $(that.view).on('close', function () {
                    that.close();
                });
            }
        };
    };
});
```

index.html

```
<script data-main="/app" src="/Lib/requirejs.js"></script>
```

Steps through goes execution flow are next:

- app.js init requrejs options and run Router.js
- Router detects current page and runs fit controller (in this example it is PublicPageController)
- In controller runs Modules (pay attention for NotificationModule)
- Notification module registers callback for socketio event 'notificationsLoaded' which returns notification data. In registered callback NotificationModule tries to create notification objects (for example Entity/SystemNotification). Each Notification it is child of base class Entity/Notification
- In Entity/SystemNotification constructor I try to call var parent = Notification.call(this, id, socket); for inheritance realization, but sometimes Notification is UNDEFINED! It is the problem.

The above was described only for 1 case of error, there are much more places where I have the same error (undefined module)

My requirejs version is RequireJS 2.1.15

Help me pls, where is the problem?

Regards
Andrei Vorobiov

UDPATE:
the same error I see if I change

```
var parent = Notification.call(this, id, socket);
```

to

```
var parent = require('Entity/Notification').call(this, id, socket);
```

Comment: what about `Router`'s dependencies, it's the one module that bootstraps your app.

Comment: @topheman thank's for comment, but what you mean? Router depends of only jquery.

Comment: @jrburke Help, pls!:) I know only you can help me;